# Vocaboli italiani derivati dall'italiano passando per un'altra lingua

Tags: etymology, foreign-words

In questa [domanda su Spanish.SE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22988/) si chiedeva su parole della lingua spagnola che, nella sua etimologia,   avevano como origine altri vocaboli spagnoli in modo indiretto, passando per un'altra lingua. Per esempio, il vocabolo "tostón" (usato per chiamare certe [monete](https://web.archive.org/web/20080616064230/http://www.mundimoneda.com/glosario_numismatico_t.htm)) proviene dal portuguese "tostão", ma il portuguese "tostão" ha come origine il termine spagnolo "testón". Nelle risposte alla domanda menzionata potete trovare altri esempi.

La mia domanda è: questo fenomeno esiste anche nella lingua italiana? Possiamo trovare esempi di termini italiani che derivino da un vocabolo in un'altra lingua in modo che questo vocabolo proceda dall'italiano?

Prima di postare questa domanda, basandomi su un'idea che appare in una delle risposte al post su Spanish.SE, ho cercato di usare le due funzioni di ricerca del *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, "ricerca libera" e "ricerca in sequenza", per cercare "dell'it.". Potete verificare  che, purtroppo, non funzionano: la "ricerca libera" dà un messaggio d'errore di sintassi e la "ricerca in sequenza" dà dei resultati molto strani.

Comment: Neutrino... :) (è una battuta, ma non del tutto)

Comment: Mmm... Sì, @DaG, l'unico è che il nome "neutrino" fu proposto da Fermi, che era italiano.

Comment: Esatto, @Charo, e questa sarebbe l'origine italiana del nome (in particolare la desinenza -ino).

Comment: @DaG: Per questa ragione non mi è del tutto chiaro che si possa dire che derivi dall'inglese.

Comment: Dicevo infatti che è poco più di una battuta. Bisognerebbe vedere esattamente dove e quando, dopo il (di fatto) gioco di parole di Fermi, o di Amaldi, sia stata seriamente adottata la parola neutrino, e se i fisici italiani l'abbiano usata ininterrottamente dal breve periodo in cui Fermi rimase ancora in Italia dopo di allora (1934-38) o l'abbiano (ri)appresa dopo la guerra da articoli in inglese. Non è importante; sono sicuro che ci sono esempi veri e migliori.

Comment: @DaG: Forse non è importante per la risposta alla domanda, ma, secondo me, si tratta di qualcosa di interessante. Ho sentito questo aneddoto sul fatto che il primo a suggerire il nome "neutrino" fu Amaldi in una conversazione con Fermi, ma mi pare che il primo a usarlo seriamente fosse Fermi.

Comment: ...mentre Pauli lo aveva chiamato _Neutron_, nome che poi fu usato per quello che chiamiamo tuttora neutrone.

Comment: Sì, hai ragione, @DaG, ma il termine *neutron* per chiamare quello che tuttora chiamamo "neutrone" era già in uso prima del momento in cui "neutrino" fu coniato. Infatti è per questa ragione che si decise di cambiare il nome.

Comment: @DaG: Ho trovato un esempio: ["baghetta"](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000952.jpg): "Dal fr. *baguette*, a sua volta deriv. dall'ital. *bacchetta*".

Comment: Oggi mi è venuto in mente un modo di ricercare esempi sul GDLI usando la "ricerca in sequenza". La "ricerca in sequenza" non funziona bene quando si va alla pagina 2 dell'elenco dei resultati. Ma c'è una soluzione a questo problema: nell'URL che appare, cambiare "Libera" con "Sequenza". Per esempio, se si cerca "dal fr." con la "ricerca in sequenza" e si va alla pag. 2, appare 
http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Libera?q=dal%20fr.&page=2  e si deve cambiare in  http://www.gdli.it/Ricerca/Sequenza?q=dal%20fr.&page=2

Comment: Facendo appunto questa ricerca sono riuscita a trovare l'esempio che ho menzionato prima, ma mi sono accorta delle parole magiche "a sua volta". Ricercando questa sequenza con la "ricerca in sequenza" (facendo i cambi Libera --> Sequenza nelle URL come ho spiegato), con un po' di pazienza, se ne possono trovare esempi.

Answer (score 4):

Questo fenomeno si dà anche per la lingua italiana.

A continuazione elenco alcuni esempi che si trovano sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*.

## Dal francese:

- [*baghetta*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000952.jpg): Dal fr. *baguette*, a sua volta deriv. dall'ital. *bacchetta*.
- [*brico* (anche *bric* e *brik*)](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000379.jpg): Adattamento di *bric* o *brik*, voci derivate dal fr. *brick* (docum. nel 1788), alterazione dell'ingl. *brig* (nel 1720), a sua volta abbreviazione dell'ital. *brigantino*.
- [*casinò*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000841.jpg): Deriv. dal fr. *casino* (nel 1740), a sua volta derivato dall'it. *casino*.
- [*commandita*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI03/00000364.jpg): Voce mediata dalla forma francese *commandite* (nel 1673), che a sua volta deriva dall'ital. *accomandita* (v.).
- [*pennacchio* nella locuzione *fare pennacchio*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00001031.jpg): Adattamento del fr. *panache* (nella locuz. *faire panache*), che è a sua volta dall'ital. sett. *penàcio*, *pennaccio* per *pennacchio*.
- [*pedestale*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI12/00000930.jpg): Dal fr. *piédestal* (nel XVI sec.), deriv. a sua volta dall'ital. *piedistallo* (v.).
- [*pesata*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00160.jpg) nel significato di "movimento compiuto dal cavallo levandosi sulle zampe posteriori": Dal fr. *pesade* (nel 1579), che è a sua volta adattamento dell'ital. *posata*.
- [*pista*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00578.jpg) nei significati di "percorso naturale o artificiale appositamente preparato, delimitato e attrezzato per lo svolgimento di attività e di competizioni sportive [...]"; "spazio più o meno esteso e opportunamente delimitato e attrezzato per la pratica di alcuni sport (come l'hockey su ghiaccio o con pattini a rotelle, il pattinaggio, il salto con gli sci, [...]) o, anche, per altre attività ricreative o spettacolari (come il circo equestre, il ballo, l'aeromodellismo, l'autoscontro nei luna-park, ecc.)"; "spazio alquanto esteso e pavimentato (detto anche *pista aeroportuale*) adibito sia alla circolazione e alle manovre degli aerei a terra (*pista di rullaggio*) sia al decollo o all'atterraggio (detto anche, nel primo caso, *pista di lancio* e, per entrambi i casi, *pista di volo*)" e "ponte di volo di una portaerei": [...] attraverso il fr. *piste* (nel 1579), che è a sua volta dall'italiano.
- [*ridotta*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI16/00206.jpg) nei significati dell'ambito militare e altri derivati da questo per estensione, e anche quello di "luogo di ritrovo di un circolo culturale": Dal fr. *redonte*, che a sua volta è dall'ital. *ridótto*<sup>2</sup>.
- [*salone*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI17/00431.jpg) nei significati di "ambiente di vaste dimensioni adibito a ospitare mostre artistiche, rassegne tecnologiche, di moda, ecc., generalmente periodiche", "negozio di barbiere e parrucchiere per uomo elegante o con
  pretese di eleganza", "*salone di bellezza*: laboratorio di estetica, sia femminile sia maschile", "*salone di bellezza per cani*: pubblico esercizio dove i cani vengono lavati, spazzolati, rasati, disinfestati, ecc.", "trattoria con alloggio", "*salone di presa*: studio cinematografico", "*vettura salone*: carrozza passeggeri di I classe arredata con poltroncine e tavolini e dotata di un sistema di ammortizzamento migliore rispetto a quello delle altre vetture" e in locuzioni come "*aprire il salone*", "*eroe da salone*" e "*gente di saloni*": [...] dal fr. *salon* 'esposizione periodica' (cfr. il *Salon des arts* di Parigi, che in origine si teneva presso il *Grand Salon* del Louvre, da
  cui il nome), che a sua volta è prestito dall'ital.

## Dall'inglese:

- [*mascara*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI09/00000869.jpg): Dall'ingl. *mascara*, deriv. a sua volta dall'ital. *màscara*, var. ant. di *maschera*; cfr. spagn. *mascara*.
- [*sketch*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000118.jpg): Voce ingl., propr. 'schizzo, scenetta', dall'oland. *schets*, a
  sua volta dall'ital. *schizzo* (v.).
- [*skiff*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI19/00000118.jpg): Voce ingl., dal fr. *esquif*, che a sua volta è dall'ital. *schifo* (v. SCHIFO<sup>3</sup> , n. 3).
- [*studio*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000428.jpg) nel significato di "locale o complesso di locali dotato delle attrezzature per girare le scene di un film e in partic. per compiere le riprese degli interni; sala attrezzata per l'allestimento e la ripresa di una trasmissione televisiva o per la registrazione e la messa in onda di un
  programma radiofonico; ambiente predisposto per la registrazione su nastro o su disco di un brano musicale": [...] riprende l'ingl.-americ. *studio*, a sua volta dall'it.

## Alcuni dialettismi:

- [*baracello*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000054.jpg): Voce della Sardegna (corrispondente al tosc. *bargello*), deriv. dallo spagn. *barrachel* 'capo di poliziotti'
  (docum. nel 1516: anche *barrichelo*, nel 1517, e *barichelo*, nel 1536), che a sua volta discende dalla forma dell'ital.
  ant. *barigello*, più vicino all'etimo.
- [*cadastro*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI02/00000491.jpg): Voce dell'Italia settentrionale, deriv. dal fr. *cadastre*
  (1527), deriv. dal provenz. *cadastre*, a sua volta dall'ital. *catast[r]o*; e cfr. spagn. *catastro* (v. CATASTO).